# Reported speech sense

Tags: grammar

1. Direct: he said to me, "he is sick"
2. Reported: he told me that he was sick.

Supposing that someone told me he is sick. And after sometime i said this to someone using reported speech. Doesn't it make the difference as i would mean he is not sick now as we use past tense? May be he is still sick

Comment: If you know for a fact that he person still *is* sick, then you can optionally use the present tense.

Answer (score 1):

Reported / indirect speech only tells someone what happened at the time the original person said the sentence.

```
"he told me that he was sick"
    ^
    he spoke it in the past, thus past tense.
```

As such, it would mean that the person was sick at the moment he told you, since **you are simply reporting what he said**. It does not reflect whether or not he is still sick at the present moment.